# Errors in function C

Tags: c

How do I fix this function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void conversionTo(int number,int base)
{
    if(number==0)
        return;
    int remainder=number%base;    
    conversionTo((number/base),base);
    if(remainder<10)
       printf("%c",'0'+remainder);
    else
       printf("%c",'a'-10+remainder);
}   

int main()
{
    conversionTo(int number,int base);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm receiving these syntax errors : 
missing `;` before 'type`remainder: undeclared identifier
missing`)`before`type` too few arguments for call

thanks a lot!